# ManyToManyField не могу добавить обьекты

Tags: python, django

Вот ошибка:

> Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use items.set() instead.

> f = Watchlist(watcher = request.user, items = listing)

Мне нужно чтобы пользователь мог добавлять желаемые аукционы в watchlist:

```py
f = Watchlist(watcher = request.user, items = listing)
Watchlist.items.set(listing)
f.save()
for i in Listing.objects.all():
    Watchlist.items.add(i)
```

В коде сверху я попытался это сделать

вот модель `watchlist`'a:

```py
class Watchlist(models.Model):
    watcher = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Listing)
```

модель `User`:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique = True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ()
```

модель `Listing`:

```py
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length= 128)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'auctions/media/images')
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default= True, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank= True, null = True, related_name = "category", default = "None")
    price = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Как я могу реализовать эту функцию?

Django 4.1.4, Python 3.10.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ты пытаешься добавлять к `Watchlist.items.add`, добавь просто к созданному экземпляру объекта - `f.items.add`